# Encode icon font HTML entity

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, character-encoding, entity

I am using FontAwesome and would like to read the encoded HTML entity from an element containing an icon. For example, given I have this HTML in the DOM:

```
<span class="fa">&#xf005;</span>
```

How can I read the value `&#xf005;` back from an element, ? `innerHTML` gives the decoded character back.

Mathias Bynen's library [he.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he/) handles this perfectly, but for a client-side project it's a little on the heavy side for inclusion (~85kb unminified!), I would like a lightweight solution that doesn't necessarily need to cover off every edge case.

Here's a fiddle that illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ohfuffm9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/WickyNilliams/4ba14b89fbf5b3bd4b01) online which kind of did what i wanted, except that it expected entities to be decimal values. I cleaned it up a little bit (slightly weird code style origianlly), and modified to handle hex values.

```
// encode(decode) html text into html entity (assuming entity is hex)
var HtmlEntity = {
  decode : function(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#x([0-9A-F]+);/gi, function(match, dec) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(dec, 16));
    });
  },

  encode : function(str) {
    var buf = [];
    for (var i = 0, length = str.length; i < length; i++) {
      buf.push("&#x" + str[i].charCodeAt().toString(16) + ";");
    }
    return buf.join("");
  }
};

var entity = '&#x9ad8;&#x7ea7;&#x7a0b;&#x5e8f;&#x8bbe;&#x8ba1;';
var str = '高级程序设计';
console.log(HtmlEntity.decode(entity) === str); // true
console.log(HtmlEntity.encode(str) === entity); // true
```

This can easily be modified to handle hex and decimal entities, but my use case is very limited, so i opted not to.

Here's a fiddle showing the expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/ohfuffm9/4/

Answer (score 1):

The character reference `&#xf005;` is processed by the browser when parsing HTML source, and it stores just the interpreted character in the DOM. There is no way to get back the original string in the markup.

However, if you know that the element content is a single code point, like U+F005 here, no matter how it was represented in the HTML source, you can work on that code point, as a character value, in JavaScript. You can get the numeric code point value as `icon.innerHTML.charCodeAt(0)`. This value is in decimal, 61445 in the example case. If needed, convert it to hexadecimal. And you could even construct the string `&#xf005;` from it, just by adding some characters before and after the value in hex. But normally it’s simpler to just work with the character.

Comment: this is useful info, thanks. after some digging i pulled together a working solution. see my answer. I upvoted for setting me on the right path